# preg_match to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, node.js, match

```
$value = 077283331111333;    
if( ! preg_match(/^[0-9]{1,20}+$/, $value))
{
    echo $value . " is not a number that has between 1,20 digits";
}
```

I'm trying to turn this Php conditional statement into a Javascript one.

This is what I have, currently not working.

```
var value = 077283331111333;
var regex = '/^[0-9]{1,20}+$/';
var match = regex.test(value);
if ( ! match) {
    console.log(value + 'is not a number that has between 1,20 digits');
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

***Object /^[1,0]{1}+$//^[0-9]{1,20}+$/ has no method 'test'***

Any ideas? Additionally this within a node.js environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method is undefined because that's not a regex but a string.

You need to drop the quotes in order to create a `RegExp` object in javascript:

```
var regex = /^[1,0]{1}+$//^[0-9]{1,20}+$/;
```

**Anyway** I don't think that's a valid regex (because of the double slashes) you might wanna check for typos there...

A regex to check for a number between 1 and 20 digits is just:

```
var regex = /^\d{1,20}$/
```

Answer (score 3):

try to remove single quotes from your regex

```
var value = 077283331111333;
var regex = /^[1,0]{1}+$//^[0-9]{1,20}+$/;
var match = regex.test(value);
if ( ! match) {
    console.log(value + 'is not a number that has between 1,20 digits');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try remove the quotes from regex variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( /regex/.match( value ) ) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's one odd regexp... why don't you use
    `/^\d{1,20}$/.test(value)`